# Sitecore SXA Azure Search Facets Returning 400 Bad Request when there are more than 50 results

Tags: sxa, azure, sitecore-api, azure-search

I have a search page that is working correctly on my local instance using SOLR, but when we move the page to our AZURE Instance it fails.  The AZURE Instance is using AZURE Search instead SOLR.  If I reduce the number of searchable items for the search to 50 items or less it works correctly and shows the Facets correctly.

Since the request works when there are less then 50 items it seems there might be a configuration issue that i am missing.  Researching that it seems there is a $top that can be set that has a default of 50 but I do not know where I would put that setting to test if that is the issue

[image: console log error].

The Response is . "Can not convert Array to String."

This is a screenshot of the facets not working with 51 results.

[image]

this is a screenshot working with the result count reduced to less than 50 by setting the facets inside the url.

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue that needed to be fixed with a Hotfix from sitecore.

Sitecore 9.1.0 / SXA 1.8.0
[Hotfix download](https://dl.sitecore.net/hotfix/SXA/SC%20Hotfix%20305265-1%20SXA%201.8%20rev.%20181112.zip)

Comment: The hotfix download is not working anymore. I did found another [support patch](https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.305246/) but it looks like they never finished it.